# c# For Each On object that it's Ienumerable

Tags: casting

I have strange question but i hope someone can help me i have this vb.Net Code

```
For Each navigation In navigations
    If obj.GetType().GetProperty(navigation.Name) IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim childs = obj.GetType().GetProperty(navigation.Name)
        Dim childValues = childs.GetValue(obj, Nothing)
        If childValues Is Nothing Then
            Continue For
        End If

        For Each item In childValues
            If item Is Nothing Then
                Continue For
            End If

            SetValues(item, entityState)
        Next

    End If
Next
```

childValues values is object but i know it's a list of navigation properties.
and i can do thi in vb.net

```
For Each item In childValues
' Do Stuff
Next
```

sometimes childValues is `Entity collection of TEntity` and sometimes it's  `FixupCollection`. but in both scenario the above code works well.

now i want to change this code to c# and i don't know how can i do that 
can please someone explain to me how vb works and how can i do this in c#?

Comment: Why Negative Exactly?!!!! if you dont get the question dont try to answer!!!

Answer (score 1):

To start off, you can replace the `if`s with a `.Where` filter

```
navigations.Where(n => n.GetType.GetProperty(n.Name) != null) // nothing?
```

Then "convert" each `Navigation` into its children:

```
    .Select(n => obj.GetType().GetProperty(navigation.Name))
    .Select(n => childs.GetValue(obj, null)) // nothing?
```

Then replace the `if` with another `.Where` filter:

```
    .Where(chVals => chVals != null) // nothing?
```

before iterating over them

```
    .ForEach(chVals => 
        chVals.Where(item => item != nothing) // Not sure what nothing means in VB...
            .ForEach(item => SetValues(item, entityState))
    );
```

Comment: the problem in c# is casting childValues to Entity collection<Tentity> or FixupCollection and Tentity is dynamic proxy that i can not get it.

Comment: thank you for your complete answer.so there is no need to casting to exact type? how vb do this by the way ?